# JAXB generated classes: Ignore intermediate classes

Tags: jaxb

Here is a extract from my XML schema:

```
<xsd:complexType name="MyType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Numbers">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Number" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

JAXB generates me the following class:

```
public class MyType {
    protected MyType.Numbers numbers;

    public static class Numbers {
        protected List<BigDecimal> number;
    }
}
```

But I'd like to ignore this intermediate class and have something like:

```
public class MyType {
    protected List<BigDecimal> number;
}
```

Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible with JAXB only with the help of external plugins, as this modification is actually change of the model. Have a look at [@XmlElementWrapper plugin](http://www.conspicio.dk/blog/bjarne/jaxb-xmlelementwrapper-plugin).

Note: The same question was already asked on this forum ([How generate XMLElementWrapper annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447091), [Dealing with JAXB Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338245), [JAXB List Tag creating inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863655)). Please, use search first.

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work for me. `numbers` is now a List as expected.  But the getter looks like this: `public Numbers getNumbers{ return numbers; }` So the generated classes won't compile...

Comment: There might be a bug in the plugin :( Sorry, I can't do much with that, as I don't own that plugin. Please, publish in your question the generated code: at least it will help somebody else who will get the same problem.

Comment: The problem was that some of my XML elements contain unterscores in the name. E.g. `last_name`. For certain reasons I had to enable `underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"`. The result was that the variable was named `lastName` and the getter `getLast_name`. So the plugin was not able to match the variable with its getter and setter methods.

Comment: Good that is helped you. If you can publish the erroneous code + XSD, I would appreciate.