# How to advise xjc to generate Java List instead of nested class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, jax-ws

I have a piece of XSD reads as below

```
<xs:schema ...>
    <xs:element name="order" type="tns:order/>
    <xs:complexType name="order">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element .../>
            <xs:element name="itemList" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="item" type="tns:item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="item">
        <xs:sequence>
            ...
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

By default, an Order class is generated with a nested class Order.ItemList. The signature of the itemList field within Order class is:

```
protected Order.ItemList itemList;
```

However I am expecting the type of itemList is java.util.List, i.e.

```
protected List<Item> itemList;
```

How can I achieve this through the external binding file? I am aware of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863655/jaxb-list-tag-creating-inner-class) but the accepted answer doesn't work for me as **I have no control over this schema** (it is part of a WSDL)

Comment: try moving the type definition for itemList outside of the type definition for order.

Comment: @tdrury: As I mentioned in my post, I have no control over the schema, it's part of my client web service description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must annotate your *List itemList* with **@XmlElementWrapper**.
You can do it in two ways:

- Manually (not an option if you are autogenerating the classes from the schema, i.e. using xjc)
- With the [jaxb-xew-plugin](https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin) plugin.

  > The plugin is used together with the xjc from the command line or from an Ant task or via maven-jaxb2-plugin.

Related answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3683678/3517383
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7340356/3517383

Comment: XEW plugin is useful to prevent wrapper classes specially, List classes. I had a similar requirement and struggled and tried to blog about it at [YoursAndMyIdeas - Data contracts, XEW And Redundant List Wrappers](https://yoursandmyideas.com/2017/07/20/data-contracts-xsds-and-redundant-list-wrappers-xew-plugin-to-rescue/).